# Dirichlet character of order $4$ and the splitting of $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-1})$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

For $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, let $\psi$ be one of the two Dirichlet characters of order $4$ in $(\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}) ^\times$.

Consider the character sum $S = \sum_{x=0}^{p-1} \psi(x^2 - a)$, for some $a > 0$.

How can we prove that $S \bar{S} = p$? (i.e. $p$ splits as $S$ and $\bar{S}$ in $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-1})$).

Comment: For $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4$ the quadratic Gauss sum $g(\psi)$ equals $\sqrt{p}$, i.e., we have $S\overline{S}=|S|^2=(\sqrt{p})^2=p$, for $S=g(\psi)$. Is your sum $S$ related to the Gauss sum ?